# duotive-three jquery slider

Tags: jquery, image, slider, gallery

I was wondering is there a jquery tutorial or plugin that generate this effect. http://demo.duotive.org/?theme=duotive-three This is for wordpress. I don't really want to use wordpress. I would like to have my own gallery with this effect in jquery if thats possible.

Let me know. Thank you for your help

Comment: I am sure I remember seeing one, but it was a while ago and I can't remember the first thing about how to find it. You might try looking at archive on dailyjs.com from about 8 months to a year ago..